# How to combine multiple fields into one field using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity

I have an Entity table with 2 int fields and want to get all the values into a list of ints not a list of the combinations of ints

This doesn't seem to give a list of single ints

```
var allItems = (from tbl1 in objContext.MyTable
select new { tbl1.Field1, tbl1.Field2 }).ToList();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the sum of them or a single list including both field one and field 2

Comment: no sum, just the values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
var allItems = objContext.MyTable
                .SelectMany(t => new[] { t.Field1, t.Field2 })
                .ToList();
```

The first select creates an array from the two elements, then the `SelectMany` flattens that into a single enumerable.

Comment: this seems to do the job!